# Phase Shift Keying: Is it ever actually used?

Tags: signal-processing, digital-communications, digital-modulation

during my course in digital communications Phase Shift Keying is talked about where the modulation consisted of altering the phase of the carrier signal. This process takes up a lot of spectrum so I am wondering, is it ever actually used in wireless communications?

Or when PSK is talked about, is bandlimited PSK implied which amounts to QAM with a circular constellation?

Comment: GPS uses BPSK (binary phase shift keying).

Comment: does satellite TV count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most common uses of PSK is carried in (almost) everybody's pocket, the 2G GSM system. Although many phones use 3G and 4G modulation for traffic, 2G is still required for a common 'lowest level' that all support for call setup, and to revert to should 3G or 4G not be served in the area.

No commercial communication system uses raw 'PSK', as the spectrum is too wide, some form of filtering is used so all channels 'play nice' with the adjacent channels. 2G uses [GMSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-shift_keying#Gaussian_minimum-shift_keying). Although it's described as an FSK scheme, the requirement for the modulation index be exactly 0.5 means that it always goes through the same phase points and is in fact also a PSK modulation scheme.

Answer (score 6):

PSK is very much alive and used all over the place!

Let me correct a misunderstanding first:

> Or when PSK is talked about, is bandlimited PSK implied which amounts to QAM with a circular constellation?

Every communication signal is bandlimited. The constellation diagram has nothing to do with bandlimiting – that's job of the pulse shaping filter (this is an important theorem for digitall comms!). The constellation is what you see when you sample the pulse-shaped signal at the right instant, and what you multiplied with the pulses before shaping them.

Also, 4-QAM and QPSK are indistinguishable. They are identical. It's customary to draw QPSK with constellation points on the axes and 4-QAM with constellation points at odd multiples of 45°, but that's just a 45° phase shift, and phase is relative anyway. So, they are really identical.

Now, to the question, "is PSK used". Sure, all over the place!

Now, as Neil noticed, GMSK is very broadly used – GSM is indeed the most popular example! GMSK is indeed an O-QPSK system with minimal timing.

You'll find, to little surprise, that PSK systems are widely used when phase shifts don't change rapidly but magnitude might be very small or changing or generally, you'd want a fast AGC.

Satellite TV is one of these cases – I think DVB-S2 is still mainly uses QPSK. And seriously, digital TV has high data rates; so this is not a "toy example".

QPSK, 8-PSK and other modulation schemes are standardized modes for satellite telemetry modems([CCSDS 131.3-B-1](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/131x3b1.pdf)).

Satellite telephony according to the [GMR standard](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101300_101399/1013760504/01.02.01_60/ts_1013760504v010201p.pdf) uses a \$\frac\pi4\$ QPSK variant, but you'll find that's really just two alternating QPSK constellations, one shifted in phase.

The Differential (D) BPSK and QPSK modes are very popular with low-complexity systems, because you can avoid the need for phase synchronization there. For example, DAB / DAB+ are high-rate digital audio services (i.e. your next gen car radio will do that if you're in Europe), and they are heavily multicarrier systems (in fact, 2048-OFDM), but each of these carriers is DQPSK-modulated.

OQPSK systems (not only GMSK) are extremely popular in the automation sector: You'll find that IEEE802.15.4 (e.g. ZigBee) uses it as the default modulation. OQPSK is very elegant in that it has the simplicity of being QPSK (which has the simplicity of being 2× BPSK) with the benefit of not having 0-power crossings, and thus allowing for implementation of highly efficient power amplifier stages – so that your microcontroller with integrated ZigBee transceiver can work without an external amplifier, and with little battery use.

… and of course, there's thousands of RC controls that just do BPSK, because it's so simple, and still quite a bit more robust to noise than OOK of the same power. Or Wifi according to 802.11b (which uses QPSK chips, effectively). Or in fact, many spread-spectrum systems (GPS, some modes of UMTS).

Comment: QAM normally is bandlimited though using something like a Raised Cosine pulse. Raw PSK is certainly not.

Comment: No.  There's no specific thing that says that you use a pulse shaper with qam and not with psk. That is definitively not the case. In every practical system, you always use a pulse shaper. You literally can not not use one, physically.

Comment: @FourierFlux if you sit in a digital communications basics course, the fact that for (zero-mean) linear modulations, the spectral shape of your transmission is only defined by the pulse shaper and **not** by the constellation used is *very* fundamental and is something that you should probably have among the things that you should take away from that lecture, even if you don't remember all that much about modulations in general in a few years :)

Answer (score 3):

[TETRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio) uses a form of PSK.

Here, the use case requires data transmissions between fast-moving mobile stations in urban environments, where interference will cause both amplitude and phase shifts (but usually not by exact multiples of 45° on a symbol boundary, so these can be compensated for).

Comment: How does it stop the spectrum from leaking all over the place?

Comment: There is a filter in place after modulation. This makes symbol transitions slower and the amplitude more wobbly, but still clearly distinguishable from interference.

Comment: How is demodulation done then? In an ideal case you would have a PLL of some sort tracking the input but with filter it's not clear how that would still work.

Comment: @FourierFlux that's worthy of being asked in a separate question. But really, all practical transmissions are pulse-shaped *exactly* for the reason that it makes reception robuster **and** easier. You need to do timing recovery. But every but the most basic receiver does that! (And, it's really not *that* hard)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmm, ok - the thing that is still bothering me though is that is the PSK being applied directly to the carrier? I keep getting mixed information, matlabs Simulink blocks appear to modulate a baseband PSK signal which would normally get upconverted but other information implies the carrier frequency is itself phase shifted. Have any book recommendations on this?

Comment: Basically, any digital comms entry level book will show a block diagram that has data -> constellation mapper -> *pulse shaper* -> upconverter -> antenna -> channel -> antenna -> downconverter

Comment: i.e. really, in any real system you *must* have a pulse shaper of sorts, because you're right, without one, you leak all over the spectrum, and that's illegal. Just because a Matlab *simulation* doesn't do this (that's probably a deliberate simplification!) doesn't mean you don't have to.

Comment: But what does a pulse shaper in PSK really consist of and when is it applied? My digital comms book only talk about pulse shaping for QAM with respect to the RRC filter. The concept of pulse-shaped PSK I have found NOTHING on anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Many radio amateurs use PSK31 for digital communication. See the Wikipedia entry for PSK31.